# Component Methods error - Undefined variable in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am creating a **checkbox component** in **Laravel 9** and trying to access the `isChecked` method from component class as follows:

```php
// app\View\Components\form-checkbox.php
namespace App\View\Components;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class formcheckbox extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $actualValue;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $value, $actualValue)
    {
        //
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->actualValue = $actualValue;
    }

    public function isChecked($option)
    {
        return $option === $this->actualValue;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.form-checkbox');
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- resources\views\components\form-checkbox.blade.php -->
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="{{ $name }}"
            value="{{ $value }}"
            actualValue={{ $actualValue }}
            {{ $isSelected($value) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>
        {{ $slot }}
    </label>
</div>
```

When I try to render the component:

```html
<?php $val = 'Y'; ?>
<x-form-checkbox name="testChkBx[]" value="Y" actualValue="{{ $val }}"> Y </x-form-checkbox>
<x-form-checkbox name="testChkBx[]" value="YY" actualValue="{{ $val }}"> YY </x-form-checkbox>
```

It gives error:

> Undefined variable $isSelected.

I found one similar issue but could not find how to call the `isSelected` method. I am trying this with a fresh Laravel installation.

Comment: `class form-checkbox` huh I never knew you could do that! Might want to turn errors on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Errors and Fixes

You have two issues in your code:

1. The class name.
2. The method name.

[PHP classes naming rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class)

> A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

[Component Methods Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#component-methods)

> In addition to public variables being available to your component template, **any public methods on the component may be invoked**...

### Class name

For now your component is being considered as an **Anonymous Component** due to breaking the naming rules and conventions. Every call to an attribute or a method that exists only within the class scope will throw the `Undefined` error.

Beside PHP naming rules, Laravel states that a **component class is named in UpperCamelCase** and **its view is named in kebab-case**

So just recreate your component using artisan with the class name.

```
php artisan make:component FormCheckbox
```

```php
// app\View\Components\FormCheckbox.php
class FormCheckbox extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $actualValue;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $actualValue)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->actualValue = $actualValue;
    }

    public function isChecked($option): bool
    {
        return $option === $this->actualValue;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.form-checkbox');
    }
}
```

*Note that your text editor failed you and didn't point out that syntactic error!*

### Method name

Since you have defined an `isChecked` method you have to call that exact method. Because `isSelected` isn't a builtin method that will be available on any component, it was just an example for the docs.

```html
<!-- resources\views\components\form-checkbox.blade.php -->
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $name }}" value="{{ $value }}" actualValue={{ $actualValue }}
            {{ $isChecked($value) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}> {{ $slot }}
    </label>
</div>
```

---

You may need to run :

```
composer dump
php artisan optimize:clear
```

---

## Extra

You can define the `isChecked` method in these ways to clean your **Blade** code:

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $name }}" value="{{ $value }}" actualValue={{ $actualValue }}
            {{ $isChecked($value) }}> {{ $slot }}
    </label>
</div>
```

### 1

```php
    public function isChecked($option): void
    {
        if ($option === $this->actualValue)
            echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
```

### 2

```php
    public function isChecked($option): string
    {
        return $option === $this->actualValue ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    }
```